# ADFS Logout issue

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I successfully logged in ADFS Service but for logout operation I called logout endpoint URL as: https://{idp-domain}/adfs/ls?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=www.google.com

But I could not log out and i received error as:

```
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7054: The SAML logout did not complete properly.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSamlLogoutResponse(SamlContext samlContext, Boolean partialLogout, Boolean& logoutComplete)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.ProcessSignOut(SamlContext samlContext, String redirectUri, List`1 iFrameUris, Boolean partialLogout)
```

and

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name: 
wsfed

Relying Party:

```
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7054: The SAML logout did not complete properly.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSamlLogoutResponse(SamlContext samlContext, Boolean partialLogout, Boolean& logoutComplete)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.ProcessSignOut(SamlContext samlContext, String redirectUri, List`1 iFrameUris, Boolean partialLogout)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.PipelineInitiatedSignout(WrappedHttpListenerContext httpContext, String redirectUri)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolSignoutRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this issue? Is there any other endpoint for logout operation or have to configure it somewhere?

Comment: Could you look at the logevents before and after this and see if there is any more information to why it did not complete?

Comment: Make a Fiddler trace (or something similar) and look at what request fails or is skipped. And I would be surprised if that specific "wreply" would ever work.